# Game Maker Studio, script arguments not responding to variables

Tags: arguments, local-variables, game-maker, gml

To make my game more dynamic, I have created a script in which arguments are used in order to be substituted by pre defined variables.

Upon clicking the left mouse_button, there is the code:

```
script_execute(scrShoot, weapon1, ammo1);
```

Where weapon1 and ammo1 are local variables.

The simple script 'scrShoot' is as follows:

```
if argument0 = 1
{
    argument1 -= 0.05;
    instance_create(x,y,objBullet);
}

if argument0 = 2
{
    argument1 -= 0.05;
    repeat(4)
    {
        instance_create(x,y,objBullet2);
    }
}
```

argument0 works as expected, being successfully substituted by weapon1, however, the variable ammo1 never decreases.

When I manually write in ammo1 in place of argument1, the script works fine; decreasing by 0.05 with every click.

Other tests using scripts have lead me to believe that the problem lies with using variables to substitute arguments: strings and numbers work as you would expect.

I have encountered this problem in more than one scenario and I'm baffled that nobody else on the internet seems to have come across the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a number as an argument to a script, you’re giving that script a *copy* of the number to work with. That is, the script doesn’t see that you’re passing it `ammo1` – it only sees that you passed it, say, `50`. The line `argument1 -= 0.05` just modifies the copy the script receives, not `ammo1` itself.

This is called passing an argument **by value** (giving the script a copy that it can modify), as opposed to **by reference** (pointing the script to a variable to modify).

See: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

GML itself doesn’t have syntax for passing arguments by-reference, so you’re out of luck. What you *can* do, I believe, is pass an instance ID (like `self` or `other`, or the result of a call to `instance_create`) to the script:

```
/// scrShoot()
var o = argument0;
if (o.weapon == 1) {
    o.ammo -= 0.05;
    instance_create(x, y, objBullet);
}
```

---

```
/// Your object
script_execute(scrShoot, self);
```